# A head start on Tivoli Common Reporting and Cognos

Tags: frameworks, reporting, cognos, tivoli

I've just started working with Tivoli Common Reporting 2.1.1 using cognos.

Already installed the TCR and configured a datasource to a db2 database by going to: Reporting-Work with reports-Connection-Configuration-Ds connections.

I want to make a small test report connecting to that data base but since I am new to this technology I don't know how to.

Read somewhere that I need to have Framework Manager to create a model and then use Report or Query studio to create a report using that model. 
Can anyone help me by guiding me on how to start making this first test report?

From these I am assuming I need this framework, then I have to configure something in that software to point to my db2 then create something of a model. 
Then use report or query to handle this model and create a report. I've been reading manuals for a few days but can't seem to get it working otherwise.
Is there anyway to get already made reports and configure them to use my db without using framework manager? since I think framework only works in windows and I installed it in a SUSE.

Answer (score 0):

Tivoli Common Reporting is not an independent product that could be bought separately. It is always shipped with other IBM Tivoli products that have some reporting capabilities. That means you should have some out of the box reports that were shipped with the Tivoli product you bought. You could open these reports in Report Studio and try to modify them. That way you will use the model of these reports, so you won't need Framework Manager.

However when you want to report on data that are not included in the model then you need to use Framework Manager. You are correct that FM is only for Windows, but that shouldn't be a problem. It connect to a TCR/Cognos server on another machine.

Also be aware that there is a license limitation: TCR is provided for free with other Tivoli products, but only for use with Tivoli data. If you want to report on your sells data then you need to purchase Cognos separately.